# How to change text when scaling in %?

Tags: css

I have this code. Text changes when scaling through vw. How to do everything the same, only through % ?

https://jsfiddle.net/Camiastrw/bdg9rotm/

CSS

```
.container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items:center;
    padding: 1rem 2rem 0.75rem 2rem;
}

.wrapper{
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
}
.qwe{
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin-right:2rem;
}

.main-content{
    max-width: calc(100vw - 15rem);
}

.text{
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Font scaling meaning font-size ?

Comment: can you please be more clear with your question.

Comment: .container { zoom: 150%; }